Issue with generating poisson arrivals in a system
I am simulating the poisson arrivals of requests in the system. I am using numpy poisson for this purpose. The code is given below:
no_of_req=500
timesteps =500
rate = no_of_req / timesteps
id=1

poisson=[]
idx=[]


for time_step in range(1, timesteps + 1):
    number_of_new_agents = np.random.poisson(rate)
    time=update_time(start_time, time_step).time()
    poisson.append(number_of_new_agents)
    idx.append(time_step) 

plt.bar(idx, poisson)

When I plot it I get the following bar

This doesnot resemble a Poisson Distribution. Where is the problem?

You are plotting the individual drawn values. If you plot the histogram of the values, you will recover the poisson distribution:
plt.hist(poisson)

